# General formula for dangerous levels of tilt of object

Tags: trigonometry

Say i have an object that is 6 kilos spread evenly and its dimensions are 40x40x20 cm, is there a general formula to calculate at which tilting(degrees) the object will start falling over?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150582/how-to-calculate-when-an-object-will-fall-over

Comment: ah thank you, i wasn't sure where to post the question but this answers mine reasonably well.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time, it's a good idea to google your question beforehand.

Comment: You are not clear about how this tilting happens. Generally the center of gravity is the point which determines the point of tilting if I understand your question.